# Django: set a user as "authenticated" without a page reload

Tags: jquery, django, authentication, registration, colorbox

In the webapp I've built, user authentication is handled in a modal, jQuery window.

**My question:**
After registration, is it possible to set the user as "authenticated" (in Django's eyes) in the parent window upon closing the modal window *without* reloading the parent window?

**The flow currently goes like this:**
1) User visits a page and clicks on a members-only feature
2) Page grays out and a modal jQuery registration box appears (I'm using Colorbox)
3) User registers with my site and closes the modal window
4) Colorbox fires off an "onClosed()" handler to refresh the parent page

I'd like to modify #4 to have the Colorbox handler call a Javascript function to set the user as "authenticated" instead of the coarse method of reloading the page.

Anyone done this before and care to share your advice?

Comment: I'd suggest Ajax? ... What needs to be done is have part of the page rerendered after the login. (Sorry I can't be more help than that.)

Comment: Thanks James. I am using Ajax for other updates on the page, but am not sure how to use it to update Django's "is_authenticated" value without reloading the page.

Comment: I'd do as Brian Suggests and the in the server your user should be authenticated. If you have a nice authenticated response then try and process the member only feature just like a logged in user.

Comment: I'm seriously confused here. It doesn't matter whether Django "knows" the user is authenticated or not before a page refresh, anyways. Django isn't doing anything with an already rendered web page sitting in a browser window. It would only matter if you did some further request through AJAX, but Django *would* know the user's authenticated status at that point. If you're just talking about changing text on the screen such as "Login" to "Welcome Joe, Logout", that would be done with the callback from the AJAX used to actually login the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself but I would suggest you authenticate/login (from the django.contrib.auth module) the user manually when the user submits the registration from and then render a response that will processed by jquery.  This response could be just a status code representing that the account was created successfully.  The response is a normal http response so it should contain the cookie info for the new sessionid in the header.  This header is processed by the browser before jQuery does anything with it so should be handled the same way as reloading an entire page.